# mysql service exiting without error

Tags: linux, opensuse, mysql

I have installed mysql-community-server on openSUSE and am having trouble starting it as a service.

I can start it using `sudo mysqld --user=mysql` without a problem and access the database normally.

Trying to start the service with `service mysql start` or `rcmysql start` results in no error, however the service does not remain running.

```
systemctl status mysql.service -l
    mysql.service - LSB: Start the MySQL database server
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
       Active: active (exited) since Fri 2015-05-29 16:22:13 ACST; 41min ago

    May 29 16:22:13 linuxbox mysql[1588]: Starting service MySQL ..done
```

edit:

```
# rcmysql status
Checking for service MySQL:                                                     unused
mysql.service - LSB: Start the MySQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2015-05-29 16:22:13 ACST; 51min ago
```

Comment: Have you checked the log files for errors from mysql?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing notable in there.

Comment: should the server service be mysqld.service or mysql.service?

Comment: According to [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.suse.general/356274) installing packages from older versions is not supported, and I was using a MySQL version built for 12.3.